# Retain information about requested URL when using curl::curl_fetch_multi

Tags: r, curl

I'm using the following code to perform multiple simultaneous requests.

```
urls <- c("https://httpbin.org/status/301", "https://httpbin.org/status/302", "https://httpbin.org/status/200")

result <- list()

p <- curl::new_pool(total_con = 10, host_con = 5, multiplex = T)

cb <- function(res) {
  result <<- append(result, list(res))
  cat("requested URL: ", url, "last URL: ", res$url, "\n\n")
}

for (url in urls) {
  curl::curl_fetch_multi(url, done = cb, handle = curl::new_handle(failonerror = F, nobody = F, followlocation = T, ssl_verifypeer = 0), pool = p)
}

curl::multi_run(pool = p)
```

As you can see, I would like to print to the console the requested URL and the URL, that finally answered with `200 ok`.

The following is printed to the console:

```
requested URL:  https://httpbin.org/status/200 last URL:  https://httpbin.org/status/200 

requested URL:  https://httpbin.org/status/200 last URL:  https://httpbin.org/get 

requested URL:  https://httpbin.org/status/200 last URL:  https://httpbin.org/get
```

The requested URL in the console output is always `https://httpbin.org/status/200`, because it's the last URL that used in the for-loop. So, that is the wrong way to do it.

How can I retain information about the initial requested URL when using `curl_fetch_multi` to use it after `multi_run` returned? That means it would be ideal if the requested URL would be added to the `res`-list to query it with something like `cat("requested URL: ", res$requested_url, "last URL: ", res$url, "\n\n")`.

Comment: Unfortunately [`curl_easy_getinfo()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) doesn't have the original URL to give back within the standard API interface and it also modifies the buffer which holds the original URL to contain redirected URLs as it works so there is no effective way to do this with the "multi" interface.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to do asynchronous POST requests using `curl_fetch_multi` and check which requests succeeded and which failed. However, due to the structure of the POST statement (all fields are in the request body) there is no identifying information whatsoever in the response object. **My solution was to generate custom callback functions which carried an identifier**.

```r
urls <- c("https://httpbin.org/status/301", "https://httpbin.org/status/302", "https://httpbin.org/status/200")

result <- list()

# create an identifier for each url
url.ids = paste0("request_", seq_along(urls))

# custom callback function generator: generate a unique function for each url
cb = function(id){
  function(res){
    result[[id]] <<- res  
  }
}
# create the list of callback functions
cbfuns = lapply(url.ids, cb)

p <- curl::new_pool(total_con = 10, host_con = 5, multiplex = T)

for (i in seq_along(urls)) {
  curl::curl_fetch_multi(urls[i], done = cbfuns[[i]], handle = curl::new_handle(failonerror = F, nobody = F, followlocation = T, ssl_verifypeer = 0), pool = p)
}

curl::multi_run(pool = p)
```

In this example, the custom callback functions are simply used to name the elements of `result`:

```r
names(result)
## [1] "request_3" "request_1" "request_2"
```

which can then be used to tie each response back to the original request.